# In django, how generic view works

Tags: python, django, generics

I have started learning django, I'm not sure how generic view works. I read django documentation several times, I can't gain clear understanding of how generic view works. Very strange but it works well. It retrieves data from the database and renders data on the browser.

Here is snippet code of ***polls/urls.py***.

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index')
```

It will go to the **IndexView** class in ***views.py***.

Here is snippet code of ***polls/views.py***.

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Question, Choice

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

When I change **template_name** as **something**, the exception has occurred as follows.

> TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/question_list.html

What does **question_list.html** mean?

Where does it come from?

And here is ***index.html***.

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

As you can see, ***index.html*** file use **latest_question_list** as a parameter but I'm not sure how can the **latest_question_list** be used.

In ***views.py*** file, what does **context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'** mean?

Where does the **'latest_question_list'** come from and how can **index.html** use **latest_question_list**?

Do I use **context_object_name** in ***views.py***?

What's the role of the **get_queryset()** function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does question_list.html mean?

> It means that there is a file inside polls dir like **index.html**
>   if you want to have a file with a diff name you have to change the name of `template_name='polls/name_of_file_inside_polls'`

Do I use context_object_name in views.py?

> The context is the place where you put some vars to use it in your templates, that's why you can use **latest_question_list**

What's the role of the get_queryset() function?

> It creates the query that is passed to the template.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what they mean.

By default, the **DetailView** generic view uses a template called **/_detail.html.** In my case, it would use the template **"polls/question_detail.html"**. The **template_name** attribute is used to tell Django to use a specific template name instead of the autogenerated default template name. I also specify the **template_name** for the **results** list view – this ensures that the results view and the detail view have a different appearance when rendered, even though they’re both a **DetailView** behind the scenes.

For **DetailView** the question variable is provided automatically – since we’re using a Django model (**Question**), Django is able to determine an appropriate name for the context variable. However, for **ListView**, the automatically generated context variable is **question_list**. To override this we provide the **context_object_name** attribute, specifying that we want to use **latest_question_list** instead.